# How to collect multiple checkbox values using FormCollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Based on Darin's answer to my question [Ho to display multiple checkbox selection based on user's selection from dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9727796/602183)
I am displaying multiple checkboxes based on dropdown selection.

Now, once the user post the form (with multiple inputs) that i have on my page, i collect all the data using FormCollection. And the problem i have is how can i pull those selected checkbox values from formcollection? The number of checkbox will change on different selection from the drop-down, so i think requesting each checkbox value will not work.

Can anyone help me with this problem.

**The flow is as shown below:**

Properties in Model

```
public class Subcategory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Flag { get; set; }
}
```

Displaying PartialView in actual view where other form inputs are there:

```
 <div id="checkboxlist">
      @if (Model.SubCategories != null)
      {
           @Html.Partial("SubCategories", Model.SubCategories)
      }
 </div>
```

PartialView SubCategories.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Entities.Subcategory>
@{
// we change the HTML field prefix so that input elements
// such as checkboxes have correct names in order to be able
// to POST the values back 
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "checkboxlist";
}
<span>subcategory</span>
<div id="subcategories" style="margin-left: 130px;margin-top: -20px;" data-role="fieldcontain">
   <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
      @Html.EditorForModel()
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

EditorTemplates Subcategory.cshtml

```
@model MyProject.Entities.Subcategory
<div class="editor-label">
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.Flag, new { type = "checkbox" })
   <label for="@Model.ID">@Model.Name</label>
   @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.Flag)
   @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.ID)
   @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.Name)
</div>
```

jquery to display checkboxes based on dropdown selection:

```
 $('#Category').change(function () {
    var subcategoriesUrl = $(this).data('subcategoriesurl');
    var categoryId = $(this).val();
    $('#checkboxlist').load(subcategoriesUrl, { category: categoryId });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `FormCollection`. That's weakly typed. Use view models. Like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(MyViewModel model)
{
    // model.BusinessSubCategories should contain a list of Subcategory
    // where for each element you could use the Flag property to see if
    // it was selected or not
    ...
}
```

Also notice that you have an inconsistency between the field prefix that you are using in your partial:

```
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "checkboxlist";
```

and the view model collection property: `Model.BusinessSubCategories`. So make sure you fix the prefix to use the correct property name if you want the default model binder to be able to populate this property when you post back.

Comment: Is there a way using FormCollection though? I changed to FormCollection to implement captcha.

Comment: Yes, there is, but be prepared to write horrible code such as: `var flag1 = fc["BusinessSubCategories[0].Flag"]`. That is to say: never do that. Never use FormCollection. I don't see what's the relation with a captcha. If you need some additional information, add a property on your view model with the correct name and then have your controller action take this view model and forget about FormCollection.